# MBProgressHUD custom view doesn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I'm trying to show an image on MBProgressHUD by using this code

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:HUD];
HUD.customView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark"]] autorelease];
HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
HUD.labelText = @"تم إرسال وزنك بنجاح";

[HUD show:YES];
[HUD hide:YES afterDelay:1.5];
```

but this is what i get

[image]

what is the problem ?

Comment: I tried your code and it is working for me. Its just that I used self.view as superview of HUD. make sure you downloaded the right image. It should be 37 x 37 pixels

Comment: You just need to put .png in the [UIImage ImageNamed], it doesnt know what the file extension is at the moment so it will just throw nothing... T

Comment: [UIImage imageNamed:] does not require the file extension when being used with a PNG.  The file extension is required, however, for other file types. For what it's worth, imageNamed will also auto-cache and will determine the correct file for the device screen scale/DPI if the file is named using Apple's graphics naming conventions, such as "myfile@2x" vs. "myfile".  In both cases, "png" will be assumed even if it isn't specified for "imageNamed:".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it is working for me.

In MBProgressHud.h file, in comments it is mentioned that

```
/**
 * The UIView (i.g., a UIIMageView) to be shown when the HUD is in MBProgressHUDModeCustomView.
 * For best results use a 37 by 37 pixel view (so the bounds match the build in indicator bounds). 
 */
```

So perhaps the image you used is missing or is noyt included. Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the images from [this link](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/tree/master/Demo/Images) in your xcode project, seems you didn't do so.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have the image named "**37x-Checkmark**" in your project. Just add the 37x-Checkmark.png image file in your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
Now it is changed with IOS &

-(IBAction)save:(id)sender
{
        HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:HUD];

        HUD.delegate = self;
        HUD.labelText = @"Initiating Entropy...";
        HUD.minSize = CGSizeMake(135.f, 135.f);
        [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}

-(void)myTask
{
    sleep(6);
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_mark_green"]];
    [v setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.frame.size.width, img.frame.size.height)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark"]];

    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    HUD.customView = v;
    HUD.labelText = nil;
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Geo-Location Cordinates Secured";
 }
```

try this and enjoy the code.